# Web scraping using ruby

Tags: ruby, json, github

I am new to programming and I have a project where I have to write a Ruby script to retrieve info on a specified repository from github, parsing the data from JSON format, and printing it in a usable format on the command line.

I have checked out mechanize guide. Any documentation that I can check in order to complete this?

Comment: I only have hpricot and mechanize installed and don't have permission to install others.

Answer (score 3):

Use Github's [Repositories API](http://develop.github.com/p/repo.html). Everything you want is done there, without scraping or weird hacks. JSON formatted responses by default.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that earlier too but the thing is I don't have curl. Any suggestion?

Comment: Use httparty as suggested by @jdc, RESTClient, or just plain old Net:HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

Following on to @Douglas' response. What you want to do is easy using the GitHub API and the HTTParty gem:

```
require 'httparty'
class Repository
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'www.github.com'
end
response = Repository.get('/api/v2/json/repos/show/joncooper/beanstalkd')

require 'awesome_print'
>> ap response.parsed_response
{
    "repository" => {
                 "name" => "beanstalkd",
                 "size" => 128,
           "created_at" => "2011/04/29 09:43:43 -0700",
             "has_wiki" => true,
               "parent" => "kr/beanstalkd",
              "private" => false,
             "watchers" => 1,
                 "fork" => true,
             "language" => "C",
                  "url" => "https://github.com/joncooper/beanstalkd",
            "pushed_at" => "2011/07/05 22:10:53 -0700",
          "open_issues" => 0,
        "has_downloads" => true,
           "has_issues" => false,
             "homepage" => "http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/",
                "forks" => 0,
          "description" => "Beanstalk is a simple, fast work queue.",
               "source" => "kr/beanstalkd",
                "owner" => "joncooper"
    }
}
```

See http://httparty.rubyforge.org/ for more.